# Message queue looping

Tags: c#, msmq

I have a console app in c# and I am trying to receive a message from a message queue until the message queue is empty.  So something like,

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue();
While(queue.notempty)
{
    queue.receive(...)
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean MSMQ or another kind of message queue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to check whether queue is empty or not. You have to receive it this way:

```
private Message Receive(MessageQueue queue)
{
   try 
   {
      return queue.Receive(TimeSpan.Zero);
   }
   catch (MessageQueueException mqe)
   {
      if (mqe.MessageQueueErrorCode == MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout)
         return null;
      throw;
   }
}
```

then you can do

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue();
Message msg;
while( (msg = Receive(queue)) != null)
{
    //process
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in C#, the [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) class should work:

```
Queue<Message> queue = GetMessageQueue();

while(queue.Count > 0)
{
     Message message = queue.Dequeue();
     // process message
}
```

If you plan to populate the queue from multiple threads, you could consider using [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) (or `BlockingCollection<T>`) instead.

---

If you are using the [MessageQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx) class for MSMQ, you can always use:

```
MessageQueue queue = ...

TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100); // Small timeout - can be very small

Message message = queue.Receive(timeout);
while (message != null)
{
      // Process message...


      message = queue.Receive(timeout);
}
```

Comment: he is about different topic: MSMQ

Comment: @Andrey: Just in case (it wasn't clear), I updated to include that, too :)

Comment: Just FYI, if you pass a timeout parameter, the Receive method will throw an exception if the timeout expires.  You have to try/catch in a loop and return null yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class PersonDetails
 {
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
 }

     const string queueName = @".\private$\PersonQueue";

     public void GetMessageFromQueue(string queueName)
     {
      MessageQueue perosnMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
     try
     {
     XmlMessageFormatter xmlMessageFormatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { 
                               (typeof(PersonDetails)) });
      perosnMessageQueue.Formatter = xmlMessageFormatter;
      perosnMessageQueue.Refresh();
      for (int i = perosnMessageQueue.GetAllMessages().Count(); i !=0; i--)
      {
      var personDetailsFromQueue =
                         (PersonDetails)perosnMessageQueue.Receive
                         (MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic).Body;

        Console.WriteLine("FistName : {0} \n LastName : {1} \n Date Time : 
         {2}",personDetailsFromQueue.FirstName, 
              personDetailsFromQueue.LastName, 
              personDetailsFromQueue.DateTime);`  
       }
```